# What determines the cost and reward for balloons in Luigi’s Balloon World?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

When picking a balloon to find in Luigi’s Balloon World, each balloon has a different price and reward. For example, one balloon may cost 10 coins to play, but give a 50 coin reward.

Rewards do increase as you rank up, but this seems to be an overall bonus that affects all balloons equally. The hiding player’s rank doesn’t seem to affect individual costs or rewards.

What determines the cost and reward for finding a balloon in Luigi’s Balloon World?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Eurogamer](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2018-02-22-super-mario-odyssey-balloon-world-4847), all balloons cost at least ten coins to play with the the entry fee and the difficulty of the balloon deciding how much it costs to play. There are many factors that determine how much of a reward you get for finding a balloon.
Some include:

- Time rewards (You get more coins if you find a balloon before the timer runs out)
- Failures (however many times another person fails to find a balloon, more coins are added on to the reward)
- Your rank (whenever you go up a rank, you gain an additional 100 coins)